# Searchfield in Sencha touch

Tags: dynamic, sencha-touch, store

I am trying to add a search field to my form in sencha touch 1.1, but after going through examples provided by sencha touch, i could not find out a way to provide a dynamic store to the search field.
I have a store which will fetch data dynamically.
The store contains list of places and when the user enters the first letter of the place,he should be given a list of places starting from that alphabet
Here is the code i have used.

```
var searchField = new Ext.form.Search({
        name : 'search',
        placeHolder: 'Search',
        useClearIcon: true,
        data:siteStore,
        autoComplete:true,


    });


inputDataForm = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    scroll: 'vertical',
    autoDestroy: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    id:'inputForm',


   initComponent: function() {



    this.items = [{
                    xtype: 'form',
                    cls: 'formClass',
                    id:'inputImageForm',                        
                    bodyPadding: '0',
                    scroll: 'vertical',


                    items: [searchField],
                  }];       

    inputDataForm.superclass.initComponent.call(this);  

   }, // End fo initComponent   

});
```

Can somebody please help.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post the store definition?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. It is working fine and I have docked the searchfield in a panel.
You can use this and I am sure it works.

```
,   dockedItems: [{
                xtype:'searchfield'
            ,   name: "searchfield"
            ,   placeHolder: 'Search Patient'
            ,   id: 'searchPat'
            ,   listeners: {
                    keyup: function(me,e){
                        var searchData = me.getValue();
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url:'your data url'
                        ,   params:{
                                filter: searchData
                            }
                        ,   scope: this
                        ,   success: function(res){
                                var rec = Ext.decode(res.responseText);
                                var def = typeof (rec.success);
                                if(def != "undefined" ){
                                    this.store.removeAll();
                                    this.store.loadData(rec.patients);
                                }
                            }
                        ,   failure:function(res){
                                console.log(res);
                            }   
                        })
                    }
                ,   scope: this
                }
```